# RewriteCond won't rewrite my URL, instead it throws and error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to strip out a single level of my new written directory to avoid repetition of entity names in my URL. The specific name of "Well service" is duplicated as I am passing both the page category and pump category to the URL to render the page and perform relevant queries.

My current URL looks like this

```
http://mysite/Wellservice/Well-Service/PumpID01
```

Although this is not a major problem from an aesthetic perspective I would like to clean the URL up further by stripping one level of "Well Service" from the URL to create something that looks like this:

```
http://mysite/Well-Service/PumpID01
```

I have tried to build a query to handle this but it causes the server to respond with an Error: 500, my query can be seen below:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?id=([\w-]+)&s=Wellservice&c=(Well-Service)$
RewriteRule ^product.php/?$ /Pumps/%2/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Have I done something wrong in my code for the Error 500 to be returned, or is it not possible to do what I am trying to do.

**NOTE:**

- Variable "id" = the pumps id to query the database
- Variable "s"  = the category the pump belongs to to refine query result
- Variable "c"  = the page category to generate any page specific styling including active state

Comment: Look at the server error logs. It'll have more detailsa bout the 500 error. A syntax error in the rewrite directives, or an infinite loop will cause one.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll check that out now.

Comment: I see nothing out of the ordinary in the error logs,

Comment: I suggest you to post your complete .htaccess so that I can suggest better ways to avoid this situation. Looking at your current code its difficult to understand what is `product.php`